# How to set events in Matlab Script for the activex Spreadsheet11?

Tags: matlab, activex

I've a problem with the activex owc11.Spreadsheet.11.

In my Matlab script I declare the activex with:

```
CONTROL='OWC11.SPREADSHEET.11';
positions=[10,10,10,10];
handles.activex1=actxcontrol(CONTROL,[positions], myFigHandle);
```

I'd like to control some events like 'SheetChange' and 'EndEdit', associating these to subfunctions (@subfunctionSheetChange, @subfunctionEndEdit).

I tried to use this code:

```
handles.activex1.registerevents({'SheetChange', '@subfunctionSheetChange'});
handles.activex1.registerevents({'EndEdit', '@subfunctionEndEdit'});
```

..but I only reach this reasult:

> ???Error using ==> comeventcallback (at line....)
>   Error firing event 'SheetChange' to MainFunction(@subfunctionSheetChange)

How can I resolve ? Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/registerevent.html):

*The eventhandler argument can be either a string that specifies the name of the event handler function, or a function handle that maps to that function.*

You seem to have mixed up [function-handle](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/function_handle.html) and function-name into string that is neither of the two.
You should be able to either use function-handles:

```
% function-handles - not strings:
handles.activex1.registerevents({'SheetChange', @subfunctionSheetChange});
handles.activex1.registerevents({'EndEdit', @subfunctionEndEdit});
```

or function-names:

```
% mind: no "@"-prefix
handles.activex1.registerevents({'SheetChange', 'subfunctionSheetChange'});
handles.activex1.registerevents({'EndEdit', 'subfunctionEndEdit'});
```